# Deleting local reference with error 'DeleteLocalRef on global reference'

Tags: android, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I create `newHttpSession` by `pEnv->NewObject(...)`

i got an error on `DeleteLocalRef` DeleteLocalRef on global reference: 0xbd6

```
m_HttpSession = pEnv->NewGlobalRef(newHttpSession);
pEnv->DeleteLocalRef(newHttpSession);
```

Is it something wrong with deleting this reference and why it is global now? Can someone explain?

Comment: Should be pEnv. JNIEnv pointer.

Comment: It looks like the local ref has been converted to global in place. Do `m_HttpSession` and `newHttpSession` have the same value?

Comment: @EJP Do `if(m_hHttpSession != newHttpSession)  pEnv->DeleteLocalRef(newHttpSession);` solve problem, if it is somehow converted i dont want to delete it, but if not i want to delete local reference. It seems to ocurr error on android 5.1.1

Comment: In my opinion this is a bug in Android, but your solution looks reasonable to me.